# Switch base url on run time using Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, koin

I'm very new to DI. I want to change the base URL of Retrofit on run time using Koin.

As of now, the base URL is mentioned in gradle...The base URL is loaded by KOIN DI....consider if I want to change baseurl for different pages then how can I change the on run time using DI in retrofit?
For eg: the base URL is different for home page, section page, and video page..all have different base urls. How to do it on run time.

Here is my retrofit provider method,

```
    private fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): ClinicalCoreService {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        //TODO : fix with reflection
        //.add(GenericCollectionAdapterFactory(ArrayList::class.java) { ArrayList() })
        .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ClinicalCoreService::class.java)
}
```

I am starting Koin in the Application class onCreate like this:

```
class ClinicCoreApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    ActivityLifecycleCallback.register(this)
    super.onCreate()
    sContext = applicationContext
    init()

    //initialize clever tap
    CleverTapAPI.setDebugLevel(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) CleverTapAPI.LogLevel.DEBUG else CleverTapAPI.LogLevel.OFF)
    val cleaverTap = CleverTapAPI.getDefaultInstance(applicationContext)
    CleverTapAPI.createNotificationChannel(sContext,PushReceiverService.PUSH_CHANNEL_ID,PushReceiverService.PUSH_CHANNEL_NAME,"Your Channel Description",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX,true)

    startKoin {
        androidContext(this@ClinicCoreApplication)
        modules(
            listOf(
                appModule,
                networkModule,
                dataMangerModule,
                viewModelModule,
                databaseModule
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the Koin network module,

```
  val networkModule = module {
    single { provideDefaultOkHttpClient(get(), get()) }
    single { provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() }
    single { provideRetrofit(get()) }
    single<SectionApi>(named(DataSource.SECTION_REMOTE)) { (SectionRemoteSource(get())) } bind SectionApi::class
    single<FaqApi>(named(DataSource.FAQ_REMOTE)) { (FaqRemoteSource(get())) } bind FaqApi::class
    single<ExaminationApi>(named(DataSource.EXAMINATION_REMOTE)) { (ExaminationRemoteSource(get())) } bind ExaminationApi::class
    single<SampleCaseApi>(named(DataSource.SAMPLE_CASE_REMOTE)) { (SampleCaseRemoteSource(get())) } bind SampleCaseApi::class
    single { get<SectionApi>(named(DataSource.SECTION_REMOTE)).getSections() }
    single<FaqContentApi>(named(DataSource.FAQ_CONTENT_REMOTE)) { (FaqContentRemoteSource(get())) } bind FaqContentApi::class
    single<ExamContentApi>(named(DataSource.EXAM_CONTENT_REMOTE)) { (ExamContentRemoteSource(get())) } bind ExamContentApi::class
}
```

Comment: I think You can add Url directly to call with `@Url` annotation .

Comment: Ok, will try this.